# How to check if select all option is checked in sumoselect

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, sumoselect.js

I have just come across [SumoSelect.js](https://hemantnegi.github.io/jquery.sumoselect/) for dropdowns in my MVC project. 
I just wanted to know if there is way to know if the select all option of the sumoselect dropdown is checked or not.
This is my sumoslect drop down code.

```
   <div>
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Territory)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Territory, Model.Territories, new { @class = "form-control", id = "ddlTerritory", multiple = "multiple", placeholder = "Select Territory" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Territory)
   </div>
```

JavaScript Code

```
 $(document).ready(function () 
  {
    $('#ddlTerritory').SumoSelect({ selectAll: true });
    if ($('#ddlTerritory')[0].sumo.selectAll())
        {
           some code
        }
  }
```

There is no mention of such method in the documentation of sumoselect.
It would be great if some one can guide me in the right direction.

Edit: As Suggested by @stephen

```
$(document).ready(function () 
      {
        $('#ddlTerritory').SumoSelect({ selectAll: true });
var isChecked = $('#ddlTerritory').closest('.SumoSelect').find('.select-all')‌​.hasClass('.select')‌​;
        if (isChecked)
            {
               some code
            }
      }
```

Comment: `selectAll: true` will make all elements selected. No need to apply condition after that..

Comment: @Rayon I get that, but i want to know if the selectAll property is true or not so that i can bind further dependent dropdowns.

Comment: Looking at the html it generates, you should be able to use `var isChecked = $('#ddlTerritory').closest('SumoSelect').find('.select-all').hasClass('.select');`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I just tried that , it throws an invalid character error at that line, Even the debugger prior to that line doesn't isn't hit due to this error. Any changes to the line of code you suggested?

Comment: Sorry - missed the class selector - should be `.closest('.SumoSelect')`

Comment: @StephenMuecke still Doesn't work stephen.

Comment: `$('#ddlTerritory').closest('SumoSelect').find('select')‌.find('option').length == ​$('#ddlTerritory').closest('SumoSelect').find('select')‌.find('option:selected').length`

Comment: According to the [demos](https://hemantnegi.github.io/jquery.sumoselect/sumoselect_demo.html) - the plugin is wrapping your `<select>` in a `<div class="SumoSelect ... >` which contains a `<p class="select-all">` and that `<p>` element becomes `<p class="select-all select">` so it should work - oops - it should also be `.hasClass('select')`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I understood the logic behind your line of code, but it still shows invalid character error.

Comment: How are you calling it (just using the code I showed with the corrections cant generate that error?

Comment: @Rayon it expects a ' ; ' or a ' ) ' and throws an error at 'find'

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have updated the question with the line of code you suggested.

Comment: You did not correct the `.​hasClass('select')‌​` bit. But there would be no point putting that code in `$(document).ready()` - you need to check it in response to user changing it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127591/discussion-between-shekar-gvr-and-stephen-muecke).

Comment: @StephenMuecke My purpose of writing the code in ready()  is to check if selectAll is checked and instead of showing the number of selectedoptions in the placeholder text, i would like to show it as ALL.

Comment: @Shekar.gvr Do you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

this quite tricky, that I count selected items with total options:

```
function isMultipleSelectAll(id) {
    var ids = $(id).val();
    let options = $(id + " option");

    let totalSelected = ids.length;
    let totalOptions = options.length;

    if (totalSelected >= totalOptions) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```